# Selector Value Disappearing

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created a selector on the Opportunities (CR304000). When selecting a value, the value is displayed and saved in the database but when refreshing the page, the value disappears and the field is blank a shown below.

**Before Refreshing:**

[image: ![Before Refreshing]

**After Refreshing**

[image: ![After Refreshing]

**Field Code**

```
#region UsrSalesPerson
       
    [PXDBString(255)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sales Person")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<SalesPerson.salesPersonID>), SubstituteKey = typeof(SalesPerson.descr)/*, DescriptionField = typeof(SalesPerson.descr)*/)]


    public virtual string UsrSalesPerson { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrSalesPerson : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrSalesPerson> { }
#endregion
```

What could be the solution to prevent the value from disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for SalesPersonID , which is an integer field, so you need to store it in another integer field.